# Error with address for jmp in inline assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, inline-assembly

What I do is

1. Get address of `ExitProcess`
2. Make space for opcode
3. Modify opcode in the space
4. Execute modified opcode by `__asm__ ("jmp %%ecx"::"c"(opcode));`

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char addr[4];
  *(int*)addr = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),"ExitProcess");

  //push 0 == 0x6a 0x00
  //call ExitProcess == 0xe8 0xd8 0x79 0xa2 0x75
  char opcode[400] = {0x6a, 0x00, 0xe8,addr[0], addr[1],addr[2],addr[3]};
  __asm__ ("jmp %%ecx" ::"c"(opcode));


  //never be here
  printf("never get here");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I expect program to exit normally, but the program terminates with a **segmentation fault**.

It seems that it jumps to somewhere, but not to the location I want it to jump.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Did you use a debugger to check where does it jump?

Comment: You can't call a function by calling jmp.  The stack frame and appropriate registers have to be set up first.

Comment: @thang thanks for your comment. but I think I didn't jmp to ExitProcess but jmp to where calling ExitProcess exist

Comment: @MohitJain gdb said that eip before __asm__ is 0x4016ce; after __asm__ is 0x28fd2c I don't get what I have to corret

Comment: You can't jump to opcode.  That is not in the code space.  Why don't you just directly call ExitProcess?  What is the motivation for this question?  This looks like an X-Y problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @thang I want to make self modifying program. that's why I do this experiment. there is no way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure `GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll")` is a valid use of `GetModuleHandle`? `GetModuleHandle` is limited to modules loaded by the calling process: See: [**GetModuleHandle function**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress give me address 75a279d8. And when I change $eip to 75a279d8 in gdb session, it properly call ExitProcess. So I think I did something wrong on other place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting aside the odd thing you are trying to do...

Your problem is the opcode e8 is a relative jump.  So you need to account for the address you are storing it at.  Something like this maybe:

**Update:** Per taeyun, account for length of x.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma pack(1)

struct mfoo {
  unsigned char x[3] = {0x6a, 0x00, 0xe8};
  void *addr;
} foo;

int main()
{
  unsigned char *a = (unsigned char *)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"),"ExitProcess");
  foo.addr = (void *)(a - sizeof(foo) - (unsigned char *)foo.x);

  __asm__ ("jmp *%%ecx" ::"c"(&foo));


  //never be here
  printf("never get here");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: after a few correction, it works! thanks alot. the address of foo.x needed to be +7